# MailTo link in outlook email body not generating correct mail

Tags: outlook, hyperlink, mailto, email-body

I am having a href MailTo link in outlook mail body as below.

```
<a href = "mailto:uipathbot@domain.com&subject=ITASK1632463&body=Product"> Product </a>
```

When I am clicking on this link, it is generating proper mail like below.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6LSP.png)

How ever when some of my colleagues are clicking on this link, their mail is generating incorrectly as below.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xmzJ.png)

We all work in Virtual Machines and all my colleagues who are having this issues have been provided Virtual Machines by a different vendor. This makes me believe there would be some difference in Virtual Machines provided by vendor which is causing this. However I am struggling to find what difference and how to resolve this issue. Kindly help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the issue. There should be ? in place of & in below html expression.

```
<a href = "mailto:uipathbot@domain.com&subject=ITASK1632463&body=Product"> Product </a>
```